# Simple finite supergroups and sporadic supergroups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Is there an analogue list with "finite simple supergroups" similar to the finite simple group classification? Are there sporadic "finite simple" supergroups?

Comment: What is a finite supergroup? My understanding of the term "supergroup" is that it referred to a group object in the category of supermanifolds.

Comment: There is the classification problem for simple Lie supergroups, see http://arxiv.org/pdf/1109.0626.pdf.